# Determine if ListItem DataContext ID matches property of parent's DataContext to highlight the item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListBox that displays a collection of skill levels as RadioButtons. I want to highlight the skill level (and display a star next to it) that was a student's previous best achievement. I have the ListBox's DataContext set to a Skill object and its ItemsSource bound to the SkillLevels collection.

Skill
+ClassSkillLevelID //The selected skill level
+PreviousBestSkillLevelID
+SkillLevels

I am able to use the ListBox's SelectedValue feature to bind ClassSkillLevelID to select the correct RadioButton. But how can I highlight the RadioButton with the skill level ID that matches PreviousBestSkillLevelID?

I tried creating a ValueConverter with a DependencyProperty so that I could set the DependencyProperty's value to PreviousBestSkillLevelID and compare each RadioButton's ID to that. But I think the converter was not in the Visual Tree so I couldn't access the parent object in order to access PreviousBestSkillLevelID:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbSkillLevels"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SkillLevels}" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ClassSkillLevelID, Converter={StaticResource nullEmptyConverter},  ConverterParameter=System.Guid}"
            SelectedValuePath="ID">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    ...
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsSelected}">
                    <RadioButton.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                        <Binding Path="ID">
                                            <Binding.Converter>
                                                <local:SkillIDMatchConverter ValueToMatch="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.PreviousBestSkillLevelID}"/>
                                            </Binding.Converter>
                                        </Binding>
                                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Color="Yellow" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" />
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </RadioButton.Style>
                </RadioButton>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This ListBox is part of a DataTemplate for a parent ItemsControl so programmatic solutions may be more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been away from WPF too long. I was making it too difficult. For some reason I was working under the impression that I could only use a DataTrigger with a single Binding or a MultiDataTrigger. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240421/using-binding-for-the-value-property-of-datatrigger-condition) got me back on track. I needed a DataTrigger with a MultiBinding to pull in both values and then a converter to convert them to true when they match:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsSelected}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,3,3">
<RadioButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource guidMatchConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ID" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox, AncestorLevel=1}" Path="DataContext.PreviousBestSkillLevelID" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Color="Yellow" Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</RadioButton.Style>
```

Where the converter is something like this:

```
public class GuidMatchConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length < 2) 
            return false;
        else
            return (Guid)values[0] == (Guid)values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```