# Binding DataTrigger's `Value` to `VModel`

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I have one int value in my Vmodel :

```
public int MaxTagCount => URLsCount.Max(tag => tag.Count);
```

And I need to connect this `MaxTagCount` with Trigger :

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Count}" Value="1149">
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
 </DataTrigger>
```

How can I replace "1149" to `MaxTagCount` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using binding for the Value property of DataTrigger condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240421/using-binding-for-the-value-property-of-datatrigger-condition)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to bind the `Value` of the `DataTrigger` to your `MaxTagCount` property, which isn't possible due to the fact that `Value` isn't a dependency property.

The most common workaround that is to pass both the `MaxTagCount` property and the `Count` property to a `MultiValueConverter`, the converter will compare those two values and return true or false. The role of the `DataTrigger` now will be to check the value returned by the converter so:

**First**, define a basic converter that compares two values like so:

```
public class CompareValuesConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values?[0].Equals(values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Second**, update your `DataTrigger` to check the returned value of the converter, and pass your values to the converter, and set your style accordingly:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding >
                        <MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <local:CompareValuesConverter/>
                        </MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <Binding Path="Count" />
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.MaxTagCount" ElementName="Main"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Notice that i am using an `ElementName` binding to get the `MaxTagCount` value since it is (most likely) defined on the global UI `DataContext` (in this case the main Window is Named `Main`), you could also use a `RelativeSource` binding.

Answer (score 1):

As already explained by @Elhamer, you can't bind to the Value property of a DataTrigger because it is not a dependency property.

As an alternative to using a multi converter, you could just add another property to your view model that returns a bool that indicates whether the `Count` and `MaxTagCount` properties are equal:

```
public bool IsMax => Count == MaxCount;
```

...and bind to this one:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMax}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

After all, a view model is nothing but a model for the view and this kind of logic makes perfect sense to implement there.

Comment: this solution is very interesting, but if  the `Max` are even always are true, trigger not work.

Comment: My bool property is = `public bool IsMax = true` and trigger like in your answer, but `DataTrigger`  does not work

Comment: This answer is somewhat incomplete and that’s probably why it’s not working for you. You also need to fire the PropertyChanged event for the IsMax property whenever either Count or MaxCount changes.

Comment: Do you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged event in your view model?